# React Native - Migrate from Expo to another way of starting app - set up emulators for andorid and ios

Tags: ios, react-native, android-emulator, expo, create-react-native-app

I have smaller RN application made with expo (expo-cli) and it is really annoying starting app every time using expo. What I want is to migrate to another way of starting app on my phone and with hot-reloading (if it is possible). If not, how can I start it on emulators? What changes should I do on current code?

What came to my mind is to create new RN app using `create-react-native-app` and move code from current app. Then install android studio for android emulator and xcode for iOS emulator etc.

But I don't know exact steps how to migrate from expo and how to setup everything work in non-expo environment, how to set up emulators, how to start app on emulators etc. Can someone explain it in details please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you run an `Expo project` on a **real device** rather than an **emulator** on your computer,

you can recognize it on the device using the `expo start` command through the `Expo app`.

However, you should be logged in with the same ID as the `Expo-cli`.

[googleplay App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=host.exp.exponent&hl=ko)   //    [Appplay App](https://apps.apple.com/kr/app/expo-client/id982107779)

If you want to run `Expo` on an **Android studio** and **xcode**, you need to separate the project into a `stand-alone app`.

You can run `expo eject` <= [you use `Expokit`](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/expokit/)